# Can I use access used by Visual Basic for building a database

Tags: database, database-design

I am the only programmer where I work (summer job) and I am a student with only a few years of programming experience. So I was asked to build a database and I am very excited about this project because hopefully I can learn a lot from this.

Using this database my manager is supposed to be able to assign work (dealing with businesses) to different people within the company using an interface (all workers have a shared drive). When workers are done with that paperwork related to the business, they can check off that its done, add comments at the bottom of the interface, and then move on to the next business. The only experience I've had with databases is some querying with SQL, and I've built GUI interfaces with JAVA. The information on the interface will be populated from Excel so workers know what businesses they are dealing with.

I've done some research and I believe the best way to build this would be building a GUI using Microsoft Visual Studio (Visual Basic) first, then figuring out a way to populate the Interface from Excel. Also because the data is pretty straight forward and not complicated I will be using MS Access to store and track the database. I know this won't be easy, but for all you geniuses out there, is this on the right path? Thanks.

Comment: Retitled as best I could.  The actual question is unclear though.  Are you looking for opinions?  Questions that solicit opinions are off-site here.

Comment: retitled back.  ok this will probably be closed soon.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant sorry, but the title doesn't seem to be what OP is looking for. Imho he's more looking for a very generic opinion on how to build things -- i.e., way too broad.

Comment: sure. close as too broad then ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I casted my vote :)

Comment: that's why I changed the title.  as is it would be closed.  retitled it might have had a chance and be of some help to OP

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I am just looking to see if  what I mentioned in the last paragraph that if that is a possible way to build the database.

Comment: right.  I changed the title to be specific about access.  My edit was rejected.  I'm not looking for discussion though and will not change it again.  However I suggest that _you_ retitle the question title to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could use whatever technology you like. Most programming languages and databases would be sufficient for this. But are you going to make a desktop application or a web application?

If you're going to make a desktop application I would pick windows forms (and choose C# as a programming language, because you said you knew java, very similar) and choose sql server express as the database (many times better than access).

Or actually it would not be much harder to make a web application in maybe asp.net with C# and have a sql server express database. The reach for this application would be much greater, because then your users would just browse to the url.

Comment: It is going to be a desktop application because we don't have straight access to the internet due to confidentiality reasons. Will C# replace Visual Basic? Or would I still use Visual Basic to create the GUI and then use C# to populate and do other things with the Interface. Truly appreciate your input by the way.

Comment: VB and C# on the .NET is the same, sort of. You can do the same stuff in both languages. C# is nowadays a lot more popular than VB (actually VB is declining in popularity). But actually it does not matter, choose which one feels the easiest and most comfortable to work with. You should propably stick with the same language through all your application, it's easiest and actually there is not benefit in mixing languages.